# Compile error with boost.graph 1.56.0 and g++ 4.6.4

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, boost, compiler-errors

Got a savage few compile errors while trying to use Boost.Graph. The error is a regression as it is not present when compiling 1.55.0. I've dug a bit but can't fix it, does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Notes:
Using the -std=c++0x compile flag

Code that will generate the errors.

```
#include "boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  using boost::adjacency_list;
  using boost::vecS;
  using boost::directedS;
  typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, directedS, boost::default_color_type> Graph;

  std::vector< std::pair<int, int> > testVec;
  auto graph = Graph( begin(testVec), end(testVec), testVec.size());

  return 0;
}
```

Errors copied out of my IDE

> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/vector.tcc:319: error: use of deleted
>   function ‘boost::detail::stored_edge_property::self&
>   boost::detail::stored_edge_property::operator=(boost::detail::stored_edge_property::self&&) [with Vertex = long unsigned int, Property =
>   boost::no_property, boost::detail::stored_edge_property::self = boost::detail::stored_edge_property]’
>
> .../boost/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:318:
>   error: ‘boost::detail::stored_edge_property::self&
>   boost::detail::stored_edge_property::operator=(boost::detail::stored_edge_property::self&&) [with Vertex = long unsigned int, Property =
>   boost::no_property, boost::detail::stored_edge_property::self = boost::detail::stored_edge_property]’ is implicitly deleted because the default
>   definition would be ill-formed:
>
> .../boost/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:318: error: base
>   ‘boost::detail::stored_edge’ does not have a move
>   assignment operator or trivial copy assignment operator
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:546: error: use of deleted
>   function ‘boost::detail::stored_edge_property::self&
>   boost::detail::stored_edge_property::operator=(boost::detail::stored_edge_property::self&&) [with Vertex = long unsigned int, Property =
>   boost::no_property, boost::detail::stored_edge_property::self = boost::detail::stored_edge_property]’

Comment: Have you looked at the diffs for stored_edge and adjacency_list.hpp from 1.55 to 1.56?  The answer is probably in there.

Comment: Not a bad idea, I'll have a look and see what's different.

Comment: bug logged on [the  boost bug tracker](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10382). It also should be noted that the compile errors do not occur on g++4.7 or 4.8, this is a g++4.6 specific problem.

Comment: @radman The bug is happening for me with gcc 4.8.5 on Ubuntu with boost 1.61.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that the implementation of `stored_edge_property` (a under-the-hood class to store edge properties) was updated for C++11 rvalue references between the version 1.55 to 1.56 (you can see it clearly by diff'ing the files). It appears that they forgot to provide a move-assignment operator for its base class `stored_edge` (and the default one is implicitly disabled by the presence of a copy-assignment operator).

This is definitely a bug and should be reported to Boost. I remember that they made a virtually identical mistake with `shared_ptr` around the 1.48 version. I guess people don't always learn from their own mistakes. The fix is trivial, but this really should have been caught before release (it seems like a very easy bug to catch in a unit-test). Please report your findings to [their bug tracker](http://www.boost.org/development/bugs.html).

N.B.: I use BGL a lot, but I have learned to distrust their `adjacency_list` implementation, especially after looking through it extensively. I now use my own implementation of it (see [here](https://github.com/mikael-s-persson/boost_graph_ext_mp)) which cuts through a lot of the fat of the monstrous implementation that the BGL carries around.

Comment: That two different Boost libraries made a similar mistake a year or two apart is not that surprising, since they're probably written by two separate groups of people.

Comment: Thanks, I'd actually just worked most of this out and was coming back to explain it. A point of clarification; in detail/adjacency_list.hpp:319-21 the default specifier has been used for stored_edge_property's move operators, you're saying this fails to work because its base doesn't have a move operator?

Comment: It fails to work because its base class, called `stored_edge`, has a copy-assignment operator, which, by C++11 rules, disables the default (implicit) move-assignment operator for that class. Without a move-assignment operator in the base class, the compiler cannot generate the default move-assignment operator for the derived class. The fix should be as simple as defining a move-assignment operator in the base class similar to the copy-assignment operator it already has (or it could even be an explicitly defaulted move-assignment operator too, I think).

Comment: Thanks Mikael, defaulting the move assignment and move constructor in `stored_edge` did the trick. My previous solution was to change the condition on :302 to be 4.7 and below to exclude 4.6, expedient but not a proper fix. I've also verified this doesn't occur on 4.7 or 4.8, any insight into why that might be?

Comment: @radman I believe that it works on 4.7 and 4.8 because the compiler can pick the copy-assignment operator from `stored_edge` instead of the implicitly disabled move-assignment operator. I'm not sure what the rules are for that, but I'm sure that the move-assign is disabled by the presence of the copy-assign, and I suspect that the compiler is allowed to pick the base-class copy-assign instead of the move-assign to implement the default derived-class move-assignment. My guess would be that 4.6 had the "disabling rule", but could not pick up the base-class copy-assign as an alternative.

Comment: sounds like a reasonable assessment, thanks for the assistance!

Comment: This bug is still there with Boost 1.57! I'm using g++ 4.6.3 and boost 1.57 on ubuntu 12.04 x86_64.
In particular, with this bug I can't compile a network theory library named `graph-tool`

Comment: @linello I know, the bug is still lingering... I've been advocating for a patch, and submitted a few options to the maintainers. But sadly, the maintenance of the BGL has been seriously lacking for at least a year now (I'm not even sure who is officially maintaining it now, because Jeremy Siek has been scarce, Jeremiah Willcock seems gone, so it seems with Andrew Sutton, and Eric Niebler has done some things, based on the revision history, and that's about it).

Comment: Seem like the bug is still here in 1.58 on my ubuntu 15.10, this seems to be the bug in boosts bugtracker for anyone that wants to follow that: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10382

Comment: Is there something I can do without modifying the boost code itself?

Comment: Update on this issue: Apparently, there was a serious messing up on the graph maintenance and all commits of the last 2 years were just added / grafted (July 2016) to the master branch. So, I guess the next version of boost should have this fix... roll-eyes...

Comment: This is ridiculous.  I'm using about 15 lines of boost graph that is nearly identical to their examples.  I've patched it twice, and now I see the newest version is broken again?  The old patch I did the last time doesn't seem to work either.  Does boost write any unit tests, or do they just ship code without compiling it?

Comment: @MikaelPersson do you have a link to this accidental roll-back?

Comment: I copied the entire file from https://github.com/boostorg/graph/blob/develop/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp and it solved by problem (again).